# Why is the number 4 being subtracted in this switch statement of a chinese zodiac program?

Tags: php

I am having trouble figuring out this equation in the php program. Can anyone please help me?

```
<?php 
$year = 2013;
switch (($year - 4) % 12) {
  case  0: $zodiac = 'Rat';  break;
  case  1: $zodiac = 'Ox';  break;
  case  2: $zodiac = 'Tiger';   break;
  case  3: $zodiac = 'Rabbit';  break;
  case  4: $zodiac = 'Dragon';  break;
  case  5: $zodiac = 'Sanke';  break;
  case  6: $zodiac = 'Horse';  break;
  case  7: $zodiac = 'Goat';  break;
  case  8: $zodiac = 'Monkey';  break;
  case  9: $zodiac = 'Rooster';  break;
  case 10: $zodiac = 'Dog';  break;
  case 11: $zodiac = 'Pig';  break;
 }
 echo "{$year} is the year of the {$zodiac}.";
?>
```

Comment: Likely related to the alignment of the Gregorian calendar with the Zodiac.

Comment: What trouble exactly do you have?

Comment: It seems like there's really no other reason for subtracting four other than to align the Zodiac and Gregorian calendars. I don't really see anything wrong with simply removing the -4 and changing the order of the switch statement to start with Monkey. It may even prevent people having this issue in the future.

Comment: The number 4 has always been tricky, but not as tricky as when the Kaiser stole the number 'twenty' in nineteen-dickety-three. I chased that rascal to get it back, but gave up after dickety-six miles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "$year - 4" part in the switch is to bring the zodiac schedule in line with the Gregorian calendar. For example, this year (2013) is the Year of the Snake.

```
2013 - 4 = 2009

2009 % 12 = 5
```

5 evaluates to "Snake" within the switch statement.

Comment: Exactly.  While you could rotate the switch so the subtraction isn't necessary, this way you have the years in their traditional order, with Ox first.